# Trying to get table data to display on two rows instead of one

Tags: php

I am trying to get data to show on two table rows instead of just one row. Here is the code I have currently:

```
<tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Body</th>
  <th>Date Posted</th>
</tr>


<tr>
   <?php 
        for ($i=0; $i<count($entries); $i++) {
           echo "<td>" . $entries[$i] . "</td>";
        }
   ?>
</tr>
```

If I try to echo a table row tag in the echo statement it doesn't match the table header values.

Thanks

(screenshot of my issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXVFV.jpg)

Comment: note: the greater than sign is outside the quotations, or probably just a typo

Comment: I did but it doesn't match up with the table header values, it just puts it on one row after the other, it doesn't put it in line with the table headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only one loop (despite all the bad programming practices it would entail), you can try this:

```
    $numberOfTableColumns = 3;
    $entries = ...;
    $j = 0;
    for ($i=1; $i<=count($entries); $i++) {
        if ($i % $numberOfTableColumns != 0){
            if ($i == 1){
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            if ($j == 1){
                $j = 0;
                echo "<tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "<td>" . $entries[$i-1] . "</td>";
        if ($i % $numberOfTableColumns == 0){
            $j = 1;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

However, one has to admit that lodev09's solution is far more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

per entries is PER row in an array. Each item can contain those fields. So, you can do it like this:

```
// process each row
foreach ($entries as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // now process each column
    foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value) {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

The result would look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>value row 1 col 1</td>
    <td>value row 1 col 2</td>
    <td>value row 1 col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>value row 2 col 1</td>
    <td>value row 2 col 2</td>
    <td>value row 2 col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>value row 3 col 1</td>
    <td>value row 3 col 2</td>
    <td>value row 3 col 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>value row 4 col 1</td>
    <td>value row 4 col 2</td>
    <td>value row 4 col 3</td>
</tr>
....
```

If this is not working for you, perhaps you can include a sample `data` from your `$entries` variable.

### EDIT 2:

Your data from your comment looks like this:

```
array(6) { 
    [0]=> string(9) "Test Post" 
    [1]=> string(59) "Test post to see if this will work in the edit post section" 
    [2]=> string(10) "2014-07-03" 
    [3]=> string(11) "Test Post 2" 
    [4]=> string(81) "I sure hope this array return displays all instead of just one, we will find out." [5]=> string(10) "2014-07-03" 
}
```

It should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Test Post"
            [1] => "Test post to see if this will work in the edit post section"
            [2] => "2014-07-03"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Test Post 2"
            [1] => "I sure hope this array return displays all instead of just one, we will find out."
            [2] => "2014-07-03"
        )

)
```

Now, examine the way you are getting your data and build something like that. If you are using `MySQL`, try my wrapper class: https://github.com/lodev09/php-mysqli-wrapper-class

Comment: Hey lodev09, I tried that but it still won't fill in the two columns on the same row, it just leaves the two blank and uses one column for all the data. Basically it looks like this:   

Title | Body | Date Posted

and using the code you gave, all the information gets listed under the title column instead of having it split up into the body and date posted columns. I hope that makes some sense as to what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: array(6) { [0]=> string(9) "Test Post" [1]=> string(59) "Test post to see if this will work in the edit post section" [2]=> string(10) "2014-07-03" [3]=> string(11) "Test Post 2" [4]=> string(81) "I sure hope this array return displays all instead of just one, we will find out." [5]=> string(10) "2014-07-03" }  

Trying to get those onto two rows through each column instead of all of it being under the title column

Comment: the structure of your data is not correct (for standard db query I mean). It should be and `array` with sub `array` for each rows. See my updated answer